# Jquery data acess in iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, window, frame, kendo-ui

I have the frame structure below:

```
<frameset rows="*" frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" border="0">
<frame src="principal.aspx" id="main">
</ frameset>
```

principal.aspx

```
<script>
var window = $ ("#window"). kendoWindow ({
         width: "50%"
         height: "50%"
         modal: true,
         visible: false,
         actions: ["Refresh", "Maximize", "Close"]
     }). date ("kendoWindow");
</ script>

<iframe SRC="URL" id="frmConteudo"> </ iframe>
<div id="window"> </ div>
```

Now I have the problem. I'm inside the frmConteudo and want to access the div window. I can access the div window without problems this way:

```
$ ("#window", frames["main"].document)
```

However the need to access. Date ("kendoWindow") and the same is void of the two forms below:

```
var frame = frames["main"].document;
$ ("#window", frame).data("kendoWindow");
$ ("#window", frame).data(frame, "kendoWindow");
```

Any idea?

Comment: If you have a separate instance of jQuery running for each page, then they don't share their `.data` caches. Try using the frame's `$` instead: `frames["main"].$("#window").data("kendoWindow")`.

Comment: As a (probably irrelevant) aside, I would avoid doing `var window = ...`, since window has a special meaning.

Comment: Kendo's examples they use `var window` a lot which is absolutely ridiculous considering it's an extremely important word... +1

Comment: Perfect @pimvdb. I use `top.frames["main"].$("#window").data("kendoWindow")` it's ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem as follows:

I added the following method in principal.aspx

```
<script>
         function GetWindow () {
             return $ ("#window") data ("kendoWindow");
         }
</ script>
```

And I'm calling from within my frame and the method using the object like this:

```
top.frames var frame = ["main"];
var window = frame.GetWindow ();
```

Following the suggestion of pimvdb also worked perfectly.

```
top.frames["main"].$("#window").data("kendoWindow");
```